# Dart value becomes dynamic during runtime. Causing TypeError: type is not a subtype of dynamic (type comes from generics)

Tags: generics, dart

I have a function that creates a value of a generic type. When I pass that value to another function within the same class that expects that generic type, dart throws  `TypeError: Closure 'closure3': type '(int) => String' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => String'` where `int` is an example of a possible generic type.

My real code is too large but I made a simplified version on dartpad.dev that illustrates the exact problem:

```dart
class Example<T> {
  final String identifier;
  final T Function(/*params*/) createModel; // for example purposes
  final String Function (T t) buildForModel; 
    
  Example({ this.identifier, this.createModel, this.buildForModel });
}

final Example<int> foo1 = Example(
  identifier: 'foo1',  
  createModel: () => 10,
  buildForModel: (i) => 'My widget from $i',
);

final Example<String> foo2 = Example(
  identifier: 'foo2',  
  createModel: () => 'some model',
  buildForModel: (s) => 'My widget from $s',
);

final Example<double> foo3 = Example(
  identifier: 'foo3',  
  createModel: () => 10.0,
  buildForModel: (d) => 'My widget from $d',
);

final List<Example> registry = [
  foo1, foo2, foo3,
];

Example deserialize(String identifier) {
  return registry.singleWhere((e) => e.identifier == identifier);
}

// Somewhere else ==================================================

void main() {
  final result = deserialize('foo1');
  final model = result.createModel(); // becomes dynamic!
  print(result.buildForModel(model)); // throws int is not a subtype of dynamic
}
```

I'm still learning dart and trying to wrap my head around the concept of reified types, but should I just refactor all my code to find another way to serialize my widget "factories" that doesn't involve iterating a list to retrieve a value or is there a way to fix the current problem?

Comment: `deserialize` is declared to return an `Example`, which is shorthand for `Example<dynamic>`.  Since `result` is `Example<dynamic>`, the static type for `result.createModel` is `dynamic Function()`, hence it returns `dynamic`.  However, your problem isn't that `model` is `dynamic`; it's that `result` is `Example<dynamic>`, which you can verify by trying `result.buildForModel(10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare the return type or else dart will assume is of type `dynamic` .

```
Example deserialize(String identifier) {
  return registry.singleWhere((e) => e.identifier == identifier);
}
```

Here you are supposed to return something with dType as `Example`, but `registry.singleWhere((e) => e.identifier == identifier)` is returning your data with the type being `dynamic`.

Explicitly convert your return like this `registry.singleWhere<Example>((e) => e.identifier == identifier)` and you will be good to go :)